# Layout weight in nested linear layout

Tags: android, android-layout

So I want to have 6 buttons in a tic tac toe layout, for which I'm using nested linear layouts.

This is the xml file for the layout:

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:context=".TicTacToeMainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">



    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/title"
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal">



    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/topright"
        android:onClick="right_click" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:layout_weight="1"

        android:id="@+id/topcenter"
        android:onClick="right_click" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:layout_weight="1"

        android:id="@+id/topleft"
        android:onClick="right_click" />

</LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/midright"
            android:onClick="right_click" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:id="@+id/midcenter"
            android:onClick="right_click" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:id="@+id/midleft"
            android:onClick="right_click" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/lowright"
            android:onClick="right_click" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:id="@+id/lowcenter"
            android:onClick="right_click" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:id="@+id/lowleft"
            android:onClick="right_click" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/reset"
        android:id="@+id/reset"
        android:onClick="right_click" />
</LinearLayout>
```

However, this renders the following screen:

[image]

How do I get the buttons to resize so that each row takes up an equal amount of space as the others, without any margins as is there in this screenshot? Also ignore the methods referenced in the buttons, as they are not made.

Comment: @MikeM. If I set the outer layout's height to 0, everything disappears. If I do so to the inner layouts, the empty space just decreases a bit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make two changes,

**1.** If you are giving `weight` to `LinearLayout` then write `layout_height="0dp"`

**2.** Height of button must be `match_parent`

So your layout would look like,

```
<LinearLayout>
    <TextView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"   //see the change here
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" //change height to match_parent
            android:text=""
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/topright"
            android:onClick="right_click" />

       //do same changes to rest two buttons within this LinearLayout

       .
       .
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout> //make same changes here

        <Button/>  //and here also
        <Button/>  //here also
        <Button/>  //here also
    </LinearrLayout>

    <LinearLayout> //make same changes here

        <Button/>  //and here also
        <Button/>  //here also
        <Button/>  //here also
    </LinearrLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="reset"
        android:id="@+id/reset"
        android:onClick="right_click" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: why does it work properly when i use fill parent instead of 0dp

Answer (score 1):

Replace all instances of `wrap_content` for the 9 `Button`s with `match_parent`.  Then to compensate for spacing taken up by the title and bottom button, change the height of the 3 horizontally-oriented `LinearLayout`s to 0dp.  Their layout weight of "1" should cause them to fill a third of the available space after the title and bottom button are laid out.

In your case, when you use `wrap_content` for the buttons, the buttons are sized such that their height will be just enough to contain the text inside of them.  Using `match_parent` will expand each button (and each interior `LinearLayout`) to fill all of the space available to it.

Comment: Sorry, my wording was not as clear as it could be, please see edit.

Comment: Your answer works, but Apurva gave the same one before you did. Thanks anyway